# How to set Unique Constraint across multiple tables in django?

Tags: sql, django, database, django-orm, unique-constraint

We have two models, they are in **One to One** relationship:

```
class A(models.Model):
    first_field_A = ...
    second_field_A = ...

class B(models.Model):
    first_field_B = ...
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need to define a Unique Constraint for `first_field_A` and `second_field_A` of model `A` and `first_field_B` of model `B`.

Is that even possible?
I have tried this:

```
class A(models.Model):

    ...

    class Meta:
        constraints = [UniqueConstraint(name='unique_constraint',
                             fields=['first_field_A', 'second_field_A', 'b__first_field_B']
                             )
        ]
```

and I've got this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: A has no field named 'b__first_field_B'
```

**Why we don't have access to fields of related tables?**
What is the alternative?

Comment: You *don't*: `UniqueConstraint` and `CheckConstraint`s span only one table (and a `CheckConstraint` only one table of that model).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What is the alternative?

Comment: Check your uniqueness constraint manually before saving.

Comment: @hendrikschneider That is not the approach I'm looking for. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your class Definition is not correct , you should move relationship field in class where you have to set unique constraints like that

```
class B(models.Model):
    first_field_B = ...
class A(models.Model):
            first_field_A = ...
            second_field_A = ...
            b = models.OneToOneField(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            class Meta:
           constraints = [UniqueConstraint(name='unique_constraint',
           fields=['first_field_A', 'second_field_A', 'b__first_field_B']
                             )]
```